# How should Kotlins Map.minus be used?

Tags: kotlin

How does Kotlins Map.minus work? I would have expected that the entries with the same key are removed.

```
fun main() 
{
    val left = mapOf(1 to "first", 2 to "second")
    val right = mapOf(1 to "first")
    val diff = left.minus(right)
    
    println(left)
    println(right)
    println(diff)  
}
```

```
Output: 
{1=first, 2=second}
{1=first}
{1=first, 2=second}

Expected: 
{1=first, 2=second}
{1=first}
{2=second}
```

From the Kotlin documentation:

> Returns a map containing all entries of the original map except the
> entry with the given key. The returned map preserves the entry
> iteration order of the original map.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The parameter of `minus` is `K`, not another map:

```
operator fun <K, V> Map<out K, V>.minus(key: K): Map<K, V>
```

So you should do:

```
val diff = left.minus(1)
// or
val diff = left - 1
```

Passing in a `Map` also compiles (but does not do what you expect) because `minus`'s receiver is a map with a covariant (`out`) key type. The compiler simply treats your `left` map as a `Map<Any, String>`, and tries to remove the key `mapOf(1 to "first")` from it. Of course, your map does not have another map as a key, so nothing is removed. Notice that the `diff` produced this way is of type `Map<Any, String>`.

Note that the documentation also says "the given key", not "the keys in the given map", so you are supposed to *give* a key here.

If you want to remove multiple keys, you can give it an `Iterable`, `Array`, or `Sequence` of *keys* (not maps!). This will call the other overloads of `minus`.

```
val diff = left - right.keys
```